# how to give more priority to the parrent element style than the child element style attribute?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to edit appearance of an HTML code that i don't know anything about that. for example i just wanna making its text cyan. regardless of it's color.
I've tried this:

```
<p style="color:cyan !important;">
   <span style="color:red;">Hello World</span>
<p>
```

don't forget this is just an example. I don't really know what will replaced with span tag. imagine this PHP code:

```
echo '<p style="color:cyan;">';
echo $HTML;// the HTML code that i want to appear in cyan
echo '</p>';
```

EDIT1:
I Can't use Internal and/or External CSS styles.

EDIT2:
or give me a PHP solution to remove all color properties from $HTML.

Comment: You can't do this with style attributes. You will probably need to target that p and style its descendants using a selector.

Comment: Then there is no solution.

Comment: If you can't add CSS styles then the only way is to remove the style attributes from your `$HTML`. If you want the parent's color to be taken, you don't need the color to be set on the child.

Comment: @Harry: Perfect Harry! please let me know how to remove any color property from $HTML. i think it's the solution.

Comment: I meant removing them at your source itself mate. You should be setting the value for `$HTML` somewhere within your code. Just remove it from there. You could use alternate ways to remove it also but that would not be worth the effort when compared to removal at source.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/P8x48/)

Following `CSS` would solve the problem. But is it a proper solution? Probably not.

CSS:

```
p > * {
    color: cyan !important;
}
```

Please refer [CSS Specificity](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20specificity) for more details.

Comment: tnx! you are correct. but i can't use internal and/or external css styles. because it isn't a whole html page. it's just an element.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inline style. It has the highest priority.

```
<p style="color: cyan">Hello World</p>
```

This is an embedded style. It has the second highest priority.

```
 <style type="text/css">
 p {color: cyan;}
 </style>
```

Using an external style sheet (.css file) is the third highest priority.

If you use the span element within the p element, and both have inline styles, the span element will have the higher priority.